# Передача данных между фрагментами через модель в Clean Architecture

Tags: android, архитектура

Подскажите поподробней как реализовать такое? Нужно передать данные, например, какие EditText или  CheckBox были выбраны на предыдущем фрагменте, чтобы работать с ними в текущем фрагменте.

Не в чистой архитектуре передавалось через

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("some_key", "some string");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Далее вытаскиваем

```
getArguments().getString("some_key")
```

Но слышал. что в чистой архитектуре это делается таким способом

> Создается модель. Эта модель является глобальной для всех презентеров
>   внутри этой активити. Остальные презентеры при надобности имеют право
>   писать в модель, а презентер фрагмента должен соответственно
>   реагировать на ее изменения" я имею ввиду взаимодействие через модель

Хотелось бы в идеале увидеть пример, как это делается. Создавать свой репозиторий, для того чтобы передать пару строк или объект между фрагментами? Я использую Dagger2 можно ли тупо провайдить

```
     Model provideModel(){ 
        return new Model();
     }
```

Сейчас у меня в каждый презентер своя модель попадает. Тогда нужно ее сделать синглтоном?
 Конкретно в моем случае я кликаю на один из элементов RecyclerView и мне нужно передать значение этого элемента.

В общем пока нет понимания правильности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Локальная модель нужна для передачи результата с экрана на предыдущий либо между двумя фрагментами на экране одновременно.

Для запуска нового экрана, параметры запуска передаются в аргументах через бандл как и всегда.
То есть схема такая:

Во вью происходит клик на элемент в списке -> у презентера вызывается метод `onItemClick(item)` -> Презентер запускает новый экран, передав ему нужные параметры

Comment: То есть не нужно усложнять работу, действуя через все слои чистой архитектуры? Правильно я понимаю, что передаем стандартными средствами? ```Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("some_key", "some string");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);```